# Trouble iteratively inserting dict into sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm going nuts. Why doesn't this work?

```
con = lite.connect('test.db')

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()    
    for key in merged_dict:
        print str(key) + ": " + str(merged_dict[key])
        cur.execute("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Games (Url, '" + str(key) + "'), VALUES ('" +merged_dict['Url'] + "', '" + str(merged_dict[key]) + "')")
```

Gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/benjamin/Documents/insertTest.py", line 7, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Games (Url, '" + str(key) + "'), VALUES ('" +merged_dict['Url'] + "', '" + str(merged_dict[key]) + "')")
OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

I also tried printing out the queries instead of executing them. This is a sample:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Games (Url, 'h1_home'), VALUES ('ILP9hhls', '0')
```

Is that an illegitimate query?

Comment: Asdf. Accepting the answer if you post it. THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be a comma before VALUES, i.e.:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Games (Url, 'h1_home') VALUES ('ILP9hhls', '0')
```

Here's a sample query for reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp